# Understand the Spring framework application backbone concept

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, gwt

Let me start by saying I was just thrown into a Spring MVC project and my only experience has been from a GWT project.

In GWT we created a hierarchy of pages filled with 'presenters' which indicated a new page. So if I wanted to create a new page I could simply create a new presenter and widget number and that number was inserted into the URL, thus creating a new web page. From there I could assign text boxes, tables, etc to that widget number, which in turn would populate my new page.

**Questions**

1. In a Spring MVC hibernate project how would I indicate I want a new page? where would information for this page be contained? Much of the Java files I see in my project are validators and logic oriented and less page structure and layout.
2. I used click listeners and handlers a lot in GWT. Why have I been unable to find any in my project's existing code base? How is this type of thing handled in Spring?

Comment: You should have edited your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639114/explaining-spring-from-gwt-perspective) and voted to re-open instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

1) MVC means model-view-controller pattern, so you need to learn how to integrate your **views** (html, jsp, jstl) into Spring.  Refer here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/view.html

2) There are also listeners in Spring, for example, ContextLoaderListener. 
These might help: 
http://www.docbyte.com/fr/blog/integrating-gwt-with-spring-and-hibernate
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35-2.html

Comment: Please update your references to the docs. Spring is at major version 4.

Comment: This is helpful but i was also looking for a paragraph or two summary similar to which I wrote about GWT if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A Spring MVC application is a web application built on top of the Servlet API. You run such an application in a Servlet container which acts as an HTTP server.

Spring MVC follows the Model-View-Controller architectural style. A controller is dispatched to handle the request based on the mappings you configure. The controller performs some logic, delegates to the model, prepares it and makes it available to the view. The view can be pretty much anything. You can have it have it generate HTML, XML, JSON, some other binary content type, etc. That content is written to the HTTP response which your HTTP client can then display/render/download.

In a typical Spring MVC app, you'll have the views setup with JSPs. Your configuration will declare an `InternalResourceViewResolver` which will forward to JSPs based on view names that the controller handler methods (methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`) return.

GWT follows a completely different methodology than Spring MVC. Spring MVC is straight up client/server. The client sends a request. Spring MVC receives it, dispatches a controller, and returns a response. The lines are clear. In GWT, not so much. IMO it feels more like a standalone application with buttons and listeners. The actual underlying implementation is still client/server, it's simply hidden from you as a developer.

When you click the button on a form, a browser typically sends an HTTP request to the server, the server responds and the browser renders some other page (or does something else, depending). In Spring, the flow is as described above. The web app receives the request, dispatches to a controller which returns a view, and then returns a response based on that view. As a developer, you code most of that.